# View value from managedObject in iOS show wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsobject

I have the following Code.

```
MbsAppDelegate *delegate = (MbsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"objekt == %@", self.objekt];

InfoLogMy(@"Objektnummer: %d", self.objekt.objektnr);
InfoLogMy(@"%@", predicate);
```

The result ist in the Log view:

```
2014-01-29 11:25:32.300 mbsApp[1672:60b] -[MbsObjektStammdatenViewController sendEmail] [Line 114] Objektnummer: 384401632
2014-01-29 11:25:32.304 mbsApp[1672:60b] -[MbsObjektStammdatenViewController sendEmail] [Line 115] objekt == <Objekt: 0x16eda5f0> (entity: Objekt; id: 0x16ec2720 <x-coredata://750A4CD1-497B-4204-8F1C-A32B4B200B10/Objekt/p3> ; data: {
adressen =     (
    "0x16ee7f20 <x-coredata://750A4CD1-497B-4204-8F1C-A32B4B200B10/Adresse/p14>",
    "0x16ee7f50 <x-coredata://750A4CD1-497B-4204-8F1C-A32B4B200B10/Adresse/p15>",
    "0x16ee8ae0 <x-coredata://750A4CD1-497B-4204-8F1C-A32B4B200B10/Adresse/p13>",
    "0x16eeb3a0 <x-coredata://750A4CD1-497B-4204-8F1C-A32B4B200B10/Adresse/p11>",
    "0x16eeb320 <x-coredata://750A4CD1-497B-4204-8F1C-A32B4B200B10/Adresse/p12>"
);
anrufer = "Herr Rappenglitz";
dateien = "<relationship fault: 0x16ec5cb0 'dateien'>";
filialname = " Grafrath";
objektanleger = Steininger;
objektnr = 1463128;
"schaden_behoben" = 0;
schadensursache = "siehe LE 1462952";
schadentag = "2013-11-21 23:00:00 +0000";
status = 0;
termin = "2013-11-21 23:00:00 +0000";
terminart = 2;
uhrzeit = "11:15:00";
uhrzeitbis = "12:15:00";
weitererhinweis = "Das w\U00e4re der Bemerkungstext der mit geschickt wird um evtl. vorher eine Telefonnummer mitzugeben um evtl. vorher kurz anrufen zu lassen.ii";
wohneinheiten =     (
    "0x16eef000 <x-coredata://750A4CD1-497B-4204-8F1C-A32B4B200B10/Wohneinheit/p1>"
);
zusatz = nil;
```

})

The value of "objektnr" in the predicate is the right one, i dont know from where the value "384401632" is coming from.

Do you have any idea?

How can i view the values from the nspredicate?

Comment: Well you are using two different values: First you are using `self.objekt` for the predicate, then for the Objektnummer you are using `self.objekt.objektnr`. Why don't you log `self.objekt` and see what number you get?

Comment: InfoLogMy(@"%@", self.objekt); => show the same result like the predicate. But also not the value 384401632. The correct value should be 1463128. I got also the value 384401632 when i would show the value  self.objekt.terminart

Comment: Maybe `InfoLogMy(@"Objektnummer: %d", self.objekt.objektnr);` the `%d` in InfoLog causes the problem? Obviously it's used for displaying decimal values, but maybe you have the number created as something else. By the way, does that also happen with other objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the Core Data generated managed object classes use `NSNumber` objects
 for Integer properties (and the output "384401632" is the *address* of that object).

So either print the number with `%@` instead of `%d`:

```
InfoLogMy(@"Objektnummer: %@", self.objekt.objektnr);
```

or convert it to an integer:

```
InfoLogMy(@"Objektnummer: %d", [self.objekt.objektnr intValue]);
```